# Получение кол-во результатов запроса с Google. PHP 5.6

Tags: php, php5

Пишу сайт, надо получить(запарсить) кол-во результатов с запроса гугл. То есть, к примеру есть запрос в гугл "Birds". И нужно получить значения (как на картинке)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я нашёл "simple_html_dom_parser" , и он может спарсить страницу. Но мне нужно только значения как на примере скриншота.

Код, который парсит все заголовки страниц:

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$curl = curl_init();
$value = "Birds";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/search?q='.$value.'');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
//echo $result;

$domResult = new simple_html_dom();
$domResult->load($result);

foreach($domResult->find('a[href^=/url?]') as $link)     //здесь и нужно поменять в find('div[result-stats]')
echo $link->plaintext . '<br>';

?>
```

А из документации(https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm):

```
// Find all element which id=foo
$ret = $html->find('#foo');

// Find all element which class=foo
$ret = $html->find('.foo');

// Find all element has attribute id
$ret = $html->find('*[id]');

// Find all anchors and images
$ret = $html->find('a, img');

// Find all anchors and images with the "title" attribute
$ret = $html->find('a[title], img[title]');
```

Но как бы я не изменял запрос с find, он ничего не выводит.

Был бы рад, если бы подсказали как и что я могу изменить в find() , чтобы мог выводится результат.

Comment: Я пришёл к выводу что, к сожалению гугл запретил легко парсить данные. Есть сервисы которые позволяет через свои сервера получать данные в формате json, но они ограниченны в запросах, и требуют подписок.